# Stretching a complex SVG based on text within it

Tags: html, svg, font-size, stretch

So I made an Illustrator SVG to work as a background of headers in a website I am designing. I am trying to find a way to dynamically resize this background SVG based on the text that is inside it. I have already used lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs", however, some of the text that I input into it becomes rather squished if it is a longer line, and rather stretched if it is a shorter line of text. I have Googled for solutions for hours to no avail (I may have found a few solutions on other stack overflow pages, however, I cannot seem to get them to work in my case. Then again, I am new to svg in html pages, so maybe it is just my ignorance that is preventing me from understanding them). I am also open to other solutions that do not involve SVGs. Here it is, please let me know if you have any questions. I also made a CodePen project if you wish to mess around with the code: https://codepen.io/jZ00codeR/pen/VgywKJ

```html
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 431.31 58.47" style="enable-background:new 0 0 431.31 58.47;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#005FB3;}
 .st1{fill:none;}
 .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st3{font-family:'neue-aachen-pro';font-weight:600;}
 .st4{font-size:40.8839px;}
 .st5{letter-spacing:-1;}
</style>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M431.31,58.47L431.31,58.47c-143.6-9.99-287.71-9.99-431.31,0l0,0l19.76-17.44c10.02-7.32,10.02-16.27,0-23.59
  L0,0l0,0c143.6,9.99,287.71,9.99,431.31,0l0,0l-19.76,17.44c-10.02,7.32-10.02,16.27,0,23.59L431.31,58.47z"/>
        <rect x="27.04" y="6.33" class="st1" width="377.23" height="45.81"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 40.04 40.407)" class="st2 st3 st4 st5 changeHead" textLength="351.23" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">This is the text that is getting squished.</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes. The text is now centered around the center of the svg element.

I'm using javascript to calculate the length of the text and resize the text if it's wider than 350units. You may decide this maxim value of 350 in base of the width of the `.st1`  rect.

```js
// the initial text size
let fontSize = 40;
txt.setAttribute("style", `font-size:${fontSize}px`);
// get the length of the text
let textLength = txt.getComputedTextLength();

while(textLength > 350){// where 350 is the max width allowed
  fontSize --
  txt.setAttribute("style", `font-size:${fontSize}px`);
  textLength = txt.getComputedTextLength();
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
text{font-family:'neue-aachen-pro';fill:#FFFFFF;}
```

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 431.31 58.47" >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#005FB3;}
 .st1{fill:none;} 
</style>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M431.31,58.47L431.31,58.47c-143.6-9.99-287.71-9.99-431.31,0l0,0l19.76-17.44c10.02-7.32,10.02-16.27,0-23.59
  L0,0l0,0c143.6,9.99,287.71,9.99,431.31,0l0,0l-19.76,17.44c-10.02,7.32-10.02,16.27,0,23.59L431.31,58.47z"/>
        <rect x="27.04" y="6.33" class="st1" width="377.23" height="45.81"/>
        <text id="txt" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="215.655" y="29.235">This is the text, a very long text.</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

This is working on Edge and IE too:
Instead of `dominant-baseline="middle"` I'm using svg `transform` to translate the text in the center.

```js
// the initial text size
var fontSize = 40;
txt.setAttribute("style", "font-size:"+fontSize+"px");
// get the length of the text
var textLength = txt.getBBox().width;

while(textLength > 350){// where 350 is the max width allowed
  fontSize --
  txt.setAttribute("style", "font-size:"+fontSize+"px");
   txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "translate(0,"+(fontSize/4)+")");
  textLength = txt.getBBox().width;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
text{font-family:'neue-aachen-pro';fill:#FFFFFF;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 431.31 58.47" >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#005FB3;}
 .st1{fill:none;} 
</style>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M431.31,58.47L431.31,58.47c-143.6-9.99-287.71-9.99-431.31,0l0,0l19.76-17.44c10.02-7.32,10.02-16.27,0-23.59
  L0,0l0,0c143.6,9.99,287.71,9.99,431.31,0l0,0l-19.76,17.44c-10.02,7.32-10.02,16.27,0,23.59L431.31,58.47z"/>
        <rect x="27.04" y="6.33" class="st1" width="377.23" height="45.81"/>
        <text id="txt"  text-anchor="middle" x="215.655" y="29.235">This is the text, a very long text.</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Beautiful! This solved my issue completely. Thank you so much. I figured that the text size could somehow be calculated with Javascript, however, as I am new to scripts, I had no idea where to start.

Comment: Thank you @JordanZoucha. In this case would you accept my answer?

Comment: any idea why this solution is not working properly on ie?

Comment: Or perhaps a better question is can you conceive of any way to make the text centered without using the dominant-baseline="middle" part? Turns out this is not supported in ie, meaning that longer text ends up disappearing towards the top.

Comment: It is almost there, however, once the text length is less than 350, the centering function does not work. I am currently messing around with it to see how to get it centered when the text is less than 350. I am assuming it would be a fairly complex function. Could you take a look at it as well? Thank you again so much for your help; this is teaching me a lot about scripting. Here is the link, everything is your updated code, save for the text statement and the font. Feel free to delete the first line of the html to get rid of the font. https://codepen.io/jZ00codeR/pen/VgywKJ

Comment: Hold up! I got closer. The pen is updated. I added 

while(textLength < 350){// where 350 is the max width allowed
   txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "translate(0,"+(fontSize/4)+")");
  textLength = txt.getBBox().width;
}

at the bottom of the script. However, the script takes awhile to load in codepen, and it is crashing the pages I am trying to use it on. Perhaps there is a way to shorten the code...(the updated code is in CodePen)

Comment: Alright, finally got it. All it took was adding txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "translate(0,"+(fontSize/4)+")"); around where the variables are defined. Let me know if there is any bad practice in my code (same codePen link).